# Authentication using $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']

Tags: php

The users when they sign up are given a default 'member_type' as "User". I'm trying to restrict access to certain pages from "Users" and unauthenticated visitors using $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] using a function stored in the header.php.

The concept is sound (I believe) but I really need some fresh eyes to help me solve the logic.

Here is the function in the header:

```
$basicAuth = array("member.php", "order.php", "logout.php");
    $adminonly = array("admin.php", "v_feedback.php", "user.php", "v_content.php", "product.php");


    restrictAccess($basicAuth, $adminonly);
```

And here is the function in its entirety:

```
function restrictAccess($basicAuth, $adminonly){
$error = "You do not have the authentication privileges to access this area, go <a href=\"index.php\" alt=\"Home\">home</a>.";

    if (isset($_SESSION['type'])){
        $auth = "Basic";

        if($_SESSION['type']=="Admin"){
            $auth = "Admin";
        }
    } else {
        $auth = "None";
    }

    //For testing purposes
    echo $auth;



if ($auth == "None"){
    if(($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']==$basicAuth)||($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']==$adminonly)){
        echo $error;
        exit();
    }
}elseif($auth =="Basic"){
    if(($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])==$adminonly){
        echo $error;
        exit();
    }
}
```

}

I have a feeling that it something to do with the logic behind the way I've structured it which is to fault.

Thank you.

Comment: Somewhat unsound.. you're depending on those filenames being accurate. What if you're messing around and temporarily have `admin2.php`, and someone discovers that by editing the url in their browser? Now they've got admin access even though it's a file they shouldn't be using.

Comment: I will just have to ensure that my file names are consistent before publishing. This isn't going to be a major web site, just a little project, however I see how it could be an issue.

Comment: I've done similar systems, but put a chunk of code at the top of a page that calls the auth function and TELLS it what level is required, e.g. `checkAccess($admin = false, $user = true, $anon = false)`. if the check fails, the function bails out and the protected code is never reached. Still doesn't help if you forget to actually call the check function in a file, but at least it's not dependent on a particular filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']==$basicAuth)` is completely wrong.
You can not compare array and a string.
`if(array_search($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'],$basicAuth) !== FALSE)` would serve, but You better use keys instead of values, and then `if(array_key_exists($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'],$basicAuth))`.
And, by the way, isn't it simplier to include "basicAuthNeeded.php" into some scripts and "adminAuthNeeded.php" into other instead of Your method?
Or else use more complex but more flexible method (define some roles, define resources and use some `checkPermissions($role, $resource)`)?